# First iOS App with MapBox SDK - Location is wrong

Tags: ios, mapbox

Just starting with Mapbox. Signed up for an account. Created a new Access Token, and copied it.

1. Started a new XCode 9.2 project.
2. Closed the project
3. Opened Cocoapods app, browsed to this project and created the podfile
4. Entered pod `'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.7'`
5. Installed the pod
6. Reopened from the Project.xcworkspace file
7. Dragged UIView onto storyboard taking up whole screen with constraints, reset it's class to `MGLMapView`
8. Added the `MGLMapboxAccessToken` to Info.plist with my Access Token as String value
9. On ViewController, I have the following code:

   ```
   import UIKit
   import Mapbox

   class ViewController: UIViewController {

       @IBOutlet weak var viewMapBox: MGLMapView!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           // Eiffel Tower - just testing...            
           viewMapBox.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.858093, longitude: 2.294694), zoomLevel: 9, animated: true)
       }

   }
   ```

Then run the app on the iPhone 8 Plus simulator. When the app is viewable, it is centred on the Ghana / Togo border in Africa!

I have the following in the console:

> 2018-01-25 09:43:24.320396+0000 MapBox1[35433:8131719] [INFO]
>   {}[Database]: recovered 19 frames from WAL file
>   /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6885A008-D320-4905-9C6E-60BF0AD4FD10/data/Containers/Data/Application/E2D43F85-2D44-4ABC-9147-B3C85256BD96/Library/Caches/com.domain.MapBox1/Cache.db-wal (Code 283) 2018-01-25 09:43:24.898002+0000 MapBox1[35433:8131726] Task
>   .<1> finished with error - code:
>   -999 2018-01-25 09:43:24.910760+0000 MapBox1[35433:8131715] Task .<1> HTTP load failed (error
>   code: -999 [1:89])

So this is the first actual steps to getting Mapbox to work. I cannot even follow any of the tutorials if this doesn't work.

Can anyone assist please? Thanks

Comment: Try doing the same code in viewWillAppear instead.

Comment: I actually commented the setCenter() line out, and manually edited the coordinates and zoom level in the Interface Builder storyboard. I then re-ran and the app started to work. Then removed this, and uncommented the line, and it continues to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work as expected by changing `animated: true` to `animated: false`. If you would like to animate the transition, you can either call set the center coordinate in a later delegate method  (such as [`mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:)), or [use an animation to change the map's camera](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/camera-animation/).

Comment: I have also seen some issues with the animations within these functions. But I also tried manually setting things in the Interface Builder, then returning to the code, and it now seems to work as expected. The same happens with the mapView.setDirection() function, so also set that to false. The UX would be much better if this can resolved. Is this a known issue with the current version of Mapbox iOS SDK?

Comment: Are you referring to setting the map's camera (in this case, the center coordinate or direction) in `viewDidLoad?` If so, it looks like you're seeing this issue: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/3859 

I'm working on getting limitation that documented!

Comment: In viewDidLoad(), I set the initial setCenter(). Then setup a button / gesture tap for the cameraThatFitsCoordinateBounds() function. Just testing currently, but there is also a shape-based equivalent of the camera bounds as well. Is that the same thing? Apologies, relative Swift newbie